# Print Access key and Secret key using client.get_caller_identity()["Account"]

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to print access key and secret key to check if I am able to connect to s3 bucket. I have created a ./aws directory in which I am having my credentials. After updating boto3 the error got changed. I have updated that below.

Code:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

ACCESS_KEY = credentials.access_key
SECRET_KEY = credentials.secret_key

client = boto3.client("sts", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_key=SECRET_KEY)

account_id = client.get_caller_identity()["Account"]
print(account_id)
```

.aws/credentisls:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = 'access_key'
aws_secret_access_key = 'secret_key'
```

With these I am getting some error:

```
ACCESS_KEY = credentials.access_key
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_key'
```

I am not sure if I am missing something in this or my code is wrong.

Comment: The first three lines are correct. I tried to replicate and the problematic expression works fine for me.

Comment: It seems you are using an older version of boto3 library, this works on newer versions. try updating the boto3 version, I am using boto3 1.12.44. There was an issue : https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using an older version of boto3 library, this works on newer versions. try updating the boto3 version.

I am using boto3 1.12.44.

There was an issue which is resolved now: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/590

Setting up AWS credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Comment: I tried to update boto3 and currently it is on
Version: 1.12.49
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services

Comment: after this error summary got changed                                                           
`ACCESS_KEY = credentials.access_key
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_key'`

Comment: kindly check if you have configured the credentials properly. Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: Hope you are using linux or mac , for windows refer here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Comment: I am using Linux